# Nested Delegate/Implementing viewDidLoad() within a Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am currently working on a project which requires that I use a delegate to pass a variable (which is already in a delegate) into another view controller.

I have a `TableView` called `MyTableView` which implements a custom class called MyCell to layout the individual cells

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
    let answerViewController = AnswerViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(answerViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
      var items = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"]

    let cell1: MyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell


    return cell1
    }
}
```

The aforementioned `MyCell` class has an extension which contains a delegate. Within this delegate there is a variable called `tagToIndex` which I would like to pass to a view controller called `AnswerViewController`

```
extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate{  
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {

    //Modifying Variable Tag To Index
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index

    //Passing Variable to Delegate
    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)

}
}
```

The way the view is setup depends on the `tagToIndex` value, so I want to implement the `viewDidLoad` function within the delegate. I will be using a series of if-else statements in the delegate function to set up the view a certain way once a `tagToIndex` condition is met (if-else statements not shown).

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController, TagToIndexDelegate {

// Accessing the variable tagToIndex passed through the delegate 
func finishPassing(dictionary: Dictionary<Int, Int>) {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
}
}
```

I have also created the protocol `tagToIndexDelegate`, but I don't think it is necessary to post on here. I have two questions:

- Where do I set the destination's delegate (i.e. where do I place the `foo.delegate = self`)
- Can I actually implement `viewDidLoad()` in a delegate like this? If so, is this proper practice?

Comment: why you want to implement the `viewDidLoad` function within the delegate. what is the benefited with this? . is there any difference  when implement `finishPassing` without  `viewDidLoad` function ?

Comment: what are trying to achieve. May be we can suggest to you simple method rather than a complex one which you are using.

Comment: The `tagToIndex` keeps track of a series of segmented controls. The `answerViewController` will look different depending on the status of these segmented controls (and thus `tagToIndex`). This is essentially a question/answer app, so there is a `tableView` controller with UILabel and one "yes" or "no" segmented control per row. When the user selects the segmented controls in a certain order, the app will segue into the `answerViewController`, who's layout depends on which questions were answered "yes" or "no"

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I set the destination's delegate (i.e. where do I place the `foo.delegate = self`)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
      var items = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"]

    let cell1: MyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
   //set the destination's delegate
    cell1.delegate = self
    return cell1
    }
}
```

> Can I actually implement `viewDidLoad()` in a delegate like this? If so, is this proper practice?

**Sorry you can not implement `viewDidLoad()` in a delegate cause it never execute. 
 `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, they will be executed before the user gets to see the view** 
this the proper way

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController, TagToIndexDelegate {

// Accessing the variable tagToIndex passed through the delegate 
func finishPassing(dictionary: Dictionary<Int, Int>) {
        //background view automatic change don't worry about that 
        view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
 }
```

Comment: I discussed this with someone briefly and it seems correct. The problem is that when I tried to implement it, Xcode corrects `cell1.delegate = self` to `cell1.delegate = self as! TagToIndexDelegate`. I am not sure why it is down casting, but whatever the reason it seems to stop the delegate from working properly.

Comment: @indiankid97 how you declare  `delegate` in the cell

Comment: Do you mean what does my `cellForRowAt` function look like?

Comment: no! I just ask how you declare the `delegate` in the `MyCell`?

Comment: Within the MyCell class I have created a delegate variable of type `TagToIndexDelegate` like so: `var delegate: TagToIndexDelegate?`